# phone detection link for email

Tags: android, iphone

I need to send out an email which contains a "Download app" link. The link should detect if the user is on an iPhone or using Android and then take them to the appropropiate download app page. However, if the user happens to open the email on their desktop (in other words, not on a phone), I need that same link to take them to my website. Is this possible? If so, how? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: include what you've tried first then ask questions where you get stuck.

Comment: Running JavaScript in emails is typically blocked for security. Let the links point to your website then on your server if you want to sniff their user agent and redirect the users to the appropriate app marketplace you can do so.

Answer (score 0):

*Instead of sending different links for different pages*, use the **same link** and when your page opens, *check the user's device* using **javascript** and then *redirect him and/or display the appropriate download page*.

You can detect user's device like this -

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    }
};
```

Once you detect the user's device, then it's on you. You can either redirect him to a different page with the downloading link for his device or you can replace the existing link using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700062/change-link-text-in-html-using-javascript/1700093#1700093).